# Dropping procedure which already exists?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error with mysql procedures ERROR 1304 & ERROR 1305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401982/error-with-mysql-procedures-error-1304-error-1305)

I try to run a command to drop a procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE create_datetable
```

By doing this I get the a warning:

```
1304 PROCEDURE create_datetable already exists
```

After that when I'm trying to create a new procedure with the same name, I get the same warning.

What does this mean?

Comment: If it makes any difference, I edited the post.

Comment: Have you tried `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS`, as suggested by @bonCodigo?

Comment: Yes, see my comment below his answer.

Answer (score 45):

Reference: [Drop Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-procedure.html).

The code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedureName;
...
```

Edit:

Can you try to rename the procedure and then try to drop it as per this post: [Rename a mysql procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644684/rename-a-mysql-procedure)?

try this:

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`create_DataTable`
SET name = '<new_proc_name>',
specific_name = '<new_proc_name>'
WHERE db = '<database>' AND
name = '<old_proc_name>';
```

**Also note: If have granted privileges to users for this procedure you will need to update the procedure name in newProcedure as well.**

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`create_DataTable`
SET Routine_name = '<new_proc_name>'
WHERE Db = '<database>' AND
  Routine_name = '<old_proc_name>';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Do you have the freedom to delete all procedures? If so please try out this post: [Drop all stored procedures in MySQL or using temporary stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027832/drop-all-stored-procedures-in-mysql-or-using-temporary-stored-procedures) and post2: [Drop all stored procedures in MySQL or using temporary stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027832/drop-all-stored-procedures-in-mysql-or-using-temporary-stored-procedures).

Comment: With this one I get `PROCEDURE does not exist`. When I'm trying to create one, it says the same. When I try to use it, it says the procedure doesn't exist.

Comment: @MikkoP I have updated the answer by adding additional routines you could try out. Please give a shot and comment.